# Distributing data with lower and upper boundaries in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, statistics

[Here's a link to a screenshot with the formula used in Column B and some sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkb9m.png)

I have a spreadsheet with 48 rows of data in column A

The values range from 0 to 19

The average of these 48 rows = 8.71

the standard deviation of the population = 3.77

I've used the STANDARDIZE function in excel in column B to return the Z-score of each item in column A given that I know the mean (8.71), std dev (3.77), and x (whatever is in column A).

For example (row 2) has:

x = 2

z = -1.779

Using the z value, I want to create an lower (4) and upper (24) boundary and calculate what the value would be in this 3rd column.

Essentially, if x = 0 (min value), then z = -2.3096, and columnC = 4 (lower boundary condition)

Conversely, if x = 19 (max value), then z = 2.9947, and columnC = 19 (upper boundary condition)

and then all other values between 0 to 19 would be calculated....

Any ideas how I can accomplish this with a formula in the column C?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot your formulas and sample data, as well as what you would expect as result? And how should they be distributed? linear?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the formula used in column B and some of the sample data.

Comment: The distribution should be such that x=mean will equal 12 in column C but the lowest x value (i.e. 0) would need to yield 4 and the highest x value (i.e. 19) would need to yield 24.

Comment: I thought the z value would help me in distributing the data but i'm at a loss for how to actually do it in Excel :(

Comment: Do you expect something like below? Note that in this example the upper boundary is 20 not 24.

Comment: Yes, that's bang on to what I was looking for (except for the upper boundary). Is that something that you had to do with VBA or is there a formula in Excel that can assist with this?

Comment: See my answer below. Hope you will understand it, needed to use a bit mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

So if your lowest original value is `0` and your highest is `19` and you want to re-distribute them from `4` to `24` and we assume that both are linear that means:

[image]

Since both are linear we have to use these formulas:

1. [image]
2. [image]

we develope the first to `c` so we get

[image]

and replace the `c` in the second equation with that so we get

[image]

and develope this to `m` as follows

[image]
[image]
[image]

If we put this togeter with our third equation above we get:

[image]

So we finally have equations for `m =` and `c =` and we can use the numbers from our old and new lower and upper bound to get:

[image]

you can use these values with

[image]

where `x` is are your old values in column A and `y` is the new distributed value in column B:

[image]

Some visualization if you change the boundaries:

[image]

---

#### Idea for a non-linear solution

If you want `4` and `24` as boundaries and the mean should be `12` the solution cannot be linear of course. But you could use for example any other formula like

[image]

So you can use this formula for column D `y2` with the following values `a`, `b`, `c` as well as calculating the mean, min and max over column D `y2`.

[image]

Then use the solver:

- Goal is: Mean `$M$15` should be 12
- secondary conditions: `$M$16 = 4` (lower boundary) and `$M$17 = 24` (upper boundary)
- variable cells are `a`, `b` and `c`: `$M$11:$M$13`

The solver will now adjust the values `a`, `b` and `c` so that you get very close to your goal and to get these results:
[image]

The min is `4` the max is almost `24` and the mean is almost `12` that is probably the closest you can get with a numeric method.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That looks exactly like what I'd want. What did you use to determine the values in column C?

Comment: Mathematics :) 2 linear equation systems that have to be solved. Give me a moment to write an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! If the distribution wasn't linear YL=4 (lower bound), YU=24 (upper bound), and have the mean = 12, would it be possible to do that piggy-backing off this or is that another model all together? Using the screenshot above, the mean of X should result in Y = 12 keeping 4 and 24 as the lower and upper bound

Comment: Well, you need to know what you actually want. Now the distribution of the new values is linear. What do you want it to be? Logarithmic, polynomic or what else? If you want to use another kind of distribution you would need to use another equation instead of `y = m ⋅ x + c` and do all the calculations I did again. The equation I used is a linear equation. Note that we cannot tell you what is correct because it actually depends on what you want. • Actually you didn't tell use the porpose for all this.

Comment: @Alexa See my edite for a non-linear idea using solver.